# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyJSONCanvas'

Tags: python, json

In windows 11, I am using WinPython64, 3.11 version.
Executed the command `pip install PyJSONCanvas` as per the instruction given in
https://pypi.org/project/PyJSONCanvas/

`import PyJSONCanvas` gives the following error in IDLE:

```
import PyJSONCanvas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyJSONCanvas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyJSONCanvas'
```

What is the cause for this error?

```
 from pyjsoncanvas import Canvas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from pyjsoncanvas import Canvas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyjsoncanvas'
```

Comment: Capitalization matters. Try `from pyjsoncanvas import Canvas`, like in the example code

Comment: For some packages, the package name used for pip installation is not the same as the imported package name in the code.

Comment: @OneCricketeer same error. updated the question